# ¿Dropdownlist con dos columnas de datos?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buenas,

Estoy trabajando sobre ASP.NET MVC y tengo el cometido de crear un **dropdownlist que muestre dos columnas** con datos provenientes de la misma tabla. Por ejemplo:

### [image: Ejemplo de dropdownlist con dos columnas]

He buscado posibles soluciones y logré la siguiente implementación. Consiste en componer un diccionario en cuyo **value** se almacena un string con formato (para encolumnar) conteniendo los datos a mostrar por fila.

```
//Controlador...
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var dic_Aut = db.tblAuthorities.ToDictionary(s => s.AutId, s =>(s.AutNombre.PadRight(70) +
    s.AutAbrev).ToString().Replace(" ","\xA0"));

    ViewBag.AutId = new SelectList(dic_Aut, "Key", "Value");

    //...

    return View();
}
```

Luego en la vista, para lograr el efecto de columnas, la fuente debe ser monospace de forma de que cada caracter ocupe el mismo espacio.

```
@*Vista...*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AutId, "Autoridad", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10 monospace">                
            @Html.DropDownList("AutId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "AutId", @class = "form-control", required = "required", placeholder = "Este dato es necesario..." })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AutId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

El resultado es algo como lo siguiente:

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta solución es parcial** puesto que:

- La fuente no es estéticamente agradable.
- Si el contenido de la primer columna supera el padding establecido (70), el texto desplaza la segunda columna.
- Sería deseable mostrar una línea divisoria como en la primera imagen.

Agradecería mucho si alguien puede orientarme hacia una mejor aproximación.

Gracias por su tiempo.
¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

al `new{}` de la `DropDownList` podes agregarle el siguiente atributo

```
@style = "width:250px; display: inline-block;"
```

Puse `width` y `display` de ejemplo, pero podrias ponerle el estilo que gustes para mejorar la fuente.

Y para el padding podrias agrandar el tamaño del item con `Width`. Otra opcion (deberias probarla) es agregarle este atributo al estilo `style="overflow:scroll;"`. Esto deberia permitirte scrollear los valores en lugar de ponerlos en la siguiente linea.

En cuanto a la linea divisoria, seguro esta usando un componente especial, esto no lo vas a lograr anexando 2 valores como lo venís haciendo, quizás debas buscar una librería que lo haga automáticamente. Ahora que lo pienso podes lograrlo de esta manera:

`Padding-left: -20px solid rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5);`.

Podes ir jugando con el grueso de pixeles y el color hasta que se parezca a lo que buscas. El -20 deberias regularlo en base a la longitud del maximo length de uno de los 2 valores.

Espero te sea util.

Saludos!

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta pero no obtuve nuevos resultados con lo que sugieres.
Probé con: Html.DropDownList("AutId", null, new { id = "AutId", class = "form-control", style = "width:300px; display: inline-block; overflow: scroll;" }) pero no veo que cambios. Tampoco con Padding-left: -20px solid rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5).
También probé ubicando los estilos en "new { htmlAttributes : new { ... }}" con los mismos ausentes resultados.

Voy a seguir probando, si logró algo significativo actualizaré. Gracias.

Comment: Vas a tener los mismos ausentes resultados mientras no agregues en style los atributos CSS correspondientes para modificar el aspecto de tu elemento. Otra opción seria modificar el aspecto refiriéndote al Id="AutId" en una hoja de estilos. Como sea, esos conocimientos deberían consultarse en la sección CSS. Te convendría conseguirte un manual de CSS y repasar bien esos conceptos por que son fundamentales, sobre todo si vas a trabajar usando mvc. Saludos.

Comment: Un par de cosas, primero no estoy seguro a que te refieres con agregar atributos CSS en lo que me sugeriste. Mi intento fue sobre agregar directamente atributos de estilo (style="..."), lo que entiendo que es equivalente a definirlos en una metaclase CSS y referenciarlos.
Por otro lado, si modifico la fuente del dropdown para que fuera cualquiera distinta de monospace, esto haría que los caracteres no ocupasen el mismo espacio y rompería esta ficción de encolumnado, ¿no?
Te agradezco tu tiempo @seojedaperez.